# where is the source code for "Powered by Drupal"

Tags: theming

Someone told me the footer text "Powered by Drupal" in Drupal7 is provided by `theme_system_powered_by()`, which is turned into a block by `system_block_info()` and `system_block_view()`. I wonder in what file(s) these functions can be found. Thanks a million.

Comment: If all you want to do is prevent "Powered by Drupal" from being displayed, you can turn off the "Powered by Drupal" block on the admin/blocks page.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the API documentation for all your needs:

- [theme_system_powered_by()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/theme_system_powered_by/7)
- [system_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_block_info/7)
- [system_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_block_view/7)

Also, please note that modifying the output of `theme_system_powered_by()` should be done using a theme hook from your theme code. If you wonder how to achieve this, [this might be a relevant article for you](http://www.packtpub.com/article/drupal%27s-theme-layer).

Answer (score 2):

All the functions are defined in the system.module file, at the following lines:

- `system_block_info()`, line 2021
- `system_block_view()`, line 2053
- `theme_system_powered_by()`, line 3387

This information is normally not useful, as the code of those functions (as other Drupal functions) is visible on the [API reference site](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal). The core modules should not be edited.